# How to open each column of a text file as separate list?

Tags: python, list, csv

How to open each column of a text file as separate list?

```
import csv    
infile = open ('data.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
col1 = [line[0] for line in reader]
print (col1)
col2 = [line[1] for line in reader]
print (col2)
But column2 is empty. Any idea???
```

The data.txt look as follows:

```
a d 1
b e 2
c f 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code `col2` is empty because after the first iteration(List comprehension for `col1`) the iterator is already exhausted.

You can `zip` with `*`:

```
import csv
with open('abc.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    c1, c2, c3 = zip(*reader)
    print c1
    print c2
    print c3
```

**Output:**

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
('d', 'e', 'f')
('1', '2', '3')
```

Comment: Might be instructive to answer this part of the question as well: "But column2 is empty. Any idea???"

Comment: @AndréCaron Added that part.

Comment: would be better if you describe the meaning of: zip(*reader) @ hcwhsa

Comment: @nils Check out the docs for [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), it is explained there.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open ('data.txt','r') as infile:
    col1= [i.strip().split(' ')[0] for i in infile]
with open ('data.txt','r') as infile:    
    col2= [i.strip().split(' ')[1] for i in infile]
    print (col1)
    print (col2)
```